# Cordova iOS add Notification Center widget

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there any way to access Notification Center and add there dynamically information from an Ionic Cordova app? What I exactly mean is on picture below. I have tried to find a plugin but I found absolutely nothing. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to achieve that?